# Clipping end and incorrect view in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

When I increase clipping to a large value (more then 4m), the model in edit mode is displayed with a little transparency.

[image]

Can I fix it?

**Environment:**

Blender 2.79 on GNU/Linux

Comment: While previewing milimitres (as per your Scene units setup) there isn't any need to see upto 10 meters. Change scene units setup (set it to meters or change far clip values, depending on the case), likely graphic card has precision errors while calculating clipping

Comment: The precision of the depth buffer goes down if you have a large range. You have set the the units for your scene to milimeters (unit scale  0.001) and yet want to work at a larger scale. A quick fix would be to set your scale to cm)

Comment: My guess is that @RayMairlot is right, however I can not reproduce the error on my system which has the same version of Blender and it is also Linux. Can you share your .blend file?